# JPMorgan Chase jobs wrongly geolocated

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If you search for JPMorgan Chase software jobs in Toronto, you get results on Stack Overflow Jobs. However, if you click through, all of these jobs are actually in Singapore but are being incorrectly placed in Scarborough, a suburb of Toronto.

All of these are wrong, click anyone:
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=Jpmorgan&l=Toronto&d=20&u=Km&tl=&td=&s=&c=CAD&ms=&mxs=&cl=&cd=

Comment: Thank you for alerting us to this issue.  We're reaching out to JP Morgan Chase to try and resolve the issue with the job locations.

Answer (score 4):

This was caused by simple human error (much like the much larger human error in which I never actually marked this resolved 6 months ago). Job listings can link externally for an application link instead of hosting the applications on site. This is clearly marked for jobs viewers as external application buttons will all have an icon indicating that it is a link off-site, while internal ones will just say "Easy Apply" and lack the icon.

At any rate, for an external link, it is just a simple text field to input a URL. When these job listings for Toronto were posted, while the contents were set for the Toronto listing, the application URL specified was accidentally entered as the one for similar Singapore listings. This information had been brought up to JP Morgan Chase and they had fixed the issue accordingly.